# How to make app self-learning

Tags: android

I am developing Android Applications since last 4 months, now i have a query and needed suggestions on the same.

Query:
What if i wanted to

> develop an application with
>   self-learning features

for e.g., depending on battery level my app service decides whether to ping server or not, i know logically i just have to put some methods regarding it, but still any suggestions and problems i may face.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Sorry but this question is too open ended to be answered.

Comment: Ya it is.. but it is open ended to me as well, anything can be made dynamic but how can i make my app self learning means it is something like if error occurs, it should take some steps from its end, but i don't think i have any idea about it so published a question here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want self learning I suggest you to use Neural networks. Some simple neural network will fulfill your requirement.

Comment: I don't have any idea over Neural Networks but seems something Neutral network between server and app on device. By the way, thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the requirement you described is about self-learning. It is mostly like some policy/configuration setting.

Comment: Lemme say, i observe battery level and note down phone's battery works only 6 hours and with application usage its only for 3 hours, my app should learn at its own and set its timers for calling locate me service and pinging the server so user's battery does not go down each and every time app is started, something like that.